# Post a form with JSONP

Tags: jquery, post, jsonp, http-post

I want to post a form with JSONP is there any feasible solution?

I want to post form to different domain from jsonp.

Comment: Show us some code, please! How is anyone supposed to answer like that?

Comment: You can only send GET request using JSONP.

Comment: @vzwick thanks for your quick response. the scenario is i have form on my server but i want post form to different server through ajax, but ajax does not allow this so i found jsonp helps to send data to diff. server it works with GET method but i want POST method which is not working with jsonp. any idea?

Comment: Don't think he really needs to show code for this, seems like a pretty straight forward question to me :S

Answer (score 4):

You cannot make a cross origin POST with JSONP.

However, you can:

1. Serialize the form into a query string and send it along with a GET request.
2. Use [CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing)](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control) if you have the luxury of being able to target only modern browsers.

Answer (score 2):

A JSONP request is just creating a script tag with a function call:

Javascript:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script src = 'url_to_post.serverside?callback=callback_function';

var callback_function(response) {
    head.removeChild(script);
    alert(response.abc); // returns def;
};
```

url_to_post.serverside:

```
callback_function({"abc": "def"});
```

Hope you can see why it only works for GET requests

:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use that on the data option of your $.POST, $.GET, $.AJAX method:

```
$('form').serialize()
```